# spring @RequestBody validation fails

Tags: spring

I have a very simple question related to the following line of code:

```
public void reject(@PathVariable int x, @Valid @NotEmpty @RequestBody String comments)
```

While debugging, the `comments` field has `""` value and should fail.

Shall this work?

I know if I wrap `comments` in a object it will work but I am wondering why it is not working in this case.

Answer (score 0):

i think, in you case, you have to use @NoBlank.

```
public void reject(@PathVariable int x, @Valid @NotBlank @RequestBody String comments)
```

See the difference here:

- @NotNull: Checks whether the value is not null, disregarding the
  content
- @NotEmpty: Checks whether the value is not null nor empty. If it has
  just empty spaces, it will allow it as not empty
- @NotBlank: Checks whether the value is not null nor empty, trimming
  the value first. It means that, it won’t allow just empty spaces

[Source.](http://www.itprogrammingtutorials.com/2015/java/hibernate/hibernate-validator-diff-notblank-notempty/)

Comment: None of those work. The value I get there is empty string `""`.